# Force IE10 to use regular Quirks mode (NOT IE5/Legacy Quirks mode)

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-10, quirks-mode, web-standards

I've been reading up on IE10 Browser vs Document types, and what I'm looking to do is find a setting (most likely a [X-UA-Compatibility Meta tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275(v=vs.85).aspx)) that'll make IE10 pages open in regular Quirks Mode (NOT the old IE5/Legacy quirks mode). Yes, to make pages open in IE5 quirks you add IE=5, but what about the new quirks mode?

To complicate things, the DOCTYPE on all my pages seems to be

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Which the [following page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955379(v=vs.85).aspx) tells me is the DOCTYPE to be used in Standards mode. I'm hopeful though since [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803(v=vs.85).aspx) says the X-UA-Compatibility tag can override the document type determined by the DOCTYPE tag.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [almost standards mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406072(v=vs.85).aspx)? Or IE10's [interoperable (HTML5) quirks mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869300(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Your current doctype declaration will trigger standards mode (also known as edge mode).

You need to use one of the doctypes described [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405912(v=vs.85).aspx) to trigger almost standards mode.

The x-ua-compatible header supports only standards modes for a given version of IE or legacy (IE5) quirks mode.  There are no options to use the header to enable almost standards mode.  (The reason, of course, is to encourage you to update your sites to use standards mode.)

The page describing interoperable quirks mode shows how to enable the mode.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: I'm not looking for Almost Standards mode (at least I think I'm not), I'm looking for the latter, Interoperable (HTML5) Quirks mode. As far as I can tell, there isn't a tag that forces the browser to enter this mode.

Comment: The page I linked describes how to enable interoperable quirks mode.  Essentially, you use an x-ua-compatible heard set to emulate IE10 behavior.  But, you also need to remove the doctype declaration; otherwise, that will trigger standards mode.